# Square Slide from Gilbert, Unable to Have Clickable Elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've built a website using a slider based off the one that is currently used on square.com that was recoded by gilbert on http://gilbert.pellegrom.me/recreating-the-square-slider/.

It seems that the slides are currently layered on top of each other and transitions in and out.  Currently I have it working great except that now I need to add linked elements on each slide. I had a friend look at it and had modified the script and css a bit and we have each slide now on the first cycle through with clickable elements on each slide.  However, when it goes back to the first screen on the second cycle, or if you click on the previous button on any slide through the first cycle it no longer allows for anything on the slide to be clickable again.  Does anyone have any solutions as how to fix this?

Here is the codepen.  http://codepen.io/typevu/full/sCvch

Answer (score 0):

I Think adding the following will solve the problem

```
.square-slider .slide.active
{
   z-index:999 !important;
}
```

It's just the anchored image is under some another image so u cant click it

Hope This Helps You

Answer (score 0):

It works, but don't set `z-index` higher than `z-index` of nav igations, because they will be hide.
 That's a pity on Safari this slider works bad (All assets are visible  fn the first slide, than by next one slide this slide's asset turns invisible, strange.) In Chrome assets displays normally unless it will start next cycle. :]